# How do I optimize scaling images in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in python using Pygame and am encountering issues with image scaling. I want to make it possible for the camera to dynamically zoom in and out, as such, I have a "zoom" variable that I want to be able to change at any moment. I have my rendering functions scaling the images according to that zoom. If the zoom is set to 1, I get around 200 - 250 fps without many issues. However, if I set that zoom to 16, I immediately drop down to 9 - 10 fps which is really unplayable. cProfiling my code reveals that the main culprit is the Pygame scaling function.

Here is the github if anyone is interested: https://github.com/EnjoyBacon7/BoredGames

I could try scaling the images beforehand and blitting those on the screen, but unless I make a few hundred of these, there is no way I can have a truly dynamic zoom. I could also try scaling only on a zoom change, but the issue would still be present during the zoom. Any ideas?

Edit: After speaking with my good friend ChatGPT, it has come up that pygame 2 uses SDL2 and supports hardware acceleration! Printing the window's info and just viewing GPU usage in both afterburner and task manager does show that my program does not take advantage of that. I cannot find any mention of hardware acceleration on google apart from the pygame docs, but even then it only quickly goes over the subject. Is HW really natively supported, and if so, how does one go about working with it?

Comment: The right way to do this is complicated, by using OpenGL or Direct3D to put your images in a texture surface.  Then the graphics card will do all of the scaling for you automatically.  That's quite an investment, however.

Comment: You seem to be calling the `pygame.transform.scale()` function every frame, which shouldn't really be necessary and as such you should be able to re-write your render functions so that they only blit required surfaces (scaling should be done every time it's required and then stored somewhere for later use).

Comment: @TimRoberts I ended up seeing some posts mentioning pyglet and other libraries to interface with OpenGL but having toyed with OpenGL a little bit I know that it is a whole other world in terms of simplicity

Comment: @chubercik That could be a temporary solution, but whenever the zoom factor changes I will still have the same issues...

Comment: @CamilleBizeul will you though? you can also introduce a refresh rate for the zoom check, meaning you'd only update the scale of any image every, say, 0.2s or any other value that'd feel smooth enough for the user but wouldn't require that much computational power to run.

Comment: *"Here is the github if anyone is interested:"* - No. You have to add the relevant information in the question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

Comment: @Rabbid76 I felt my code was not necessary to answer the question as it was purely theoretical and I wanted to develop an implementation myself. The link was only there for any curious souls. Your point is noted however. This is also my first question on StackOverflow, I apologize for the oversight.

Comment: @chubercik 0.2 seconds might be too slow but I understand your point. Hadn't thought of that, thanks. Although it still feels like I would be going around the problem, it's a step forward!

Comment: "However, if I set that zoom to 16, I immediately drop down to 9 - 10 fps which is really unplayable." Does the rendering function actually have to scale the image again every time it's drawn? Aside from only rescaling periodically, could you cache versions of the image at different zoom factors?

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. Do not edit questions to indicate that they are "solved" (I have rolled back the most recent edit). Questions need to show the question, and not any attempt at an answer - because the [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) here is to build a library. If your solution is noticeably different from what others suggested, you may consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). However, simply saying that you incorporated some advice from other answers is generally not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As commenters have mentioned, you shouldn't call the scale operation every frame. Rather you should scale the image when the scale changes and then continue to use that image until the scale changes again. If you're using the mouse wheel to scroll, you could use `MOUSEWHEEL` events to handle the scaling.

You can trade memory for speed by caching the scaled images, python has [built-in caching decorators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache).

Here's a minimal, untested example of how you could integrate this without changing your existing code excessively.

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def scale_sprite(sprite, zoom):
    return pygame.transform.scale(sprite, (zoom * 8, zoom * 16))

# change render function to use cached scaler
def renderPlayer(window, game):
    scaled_player = scale_sprite(game.sprites["player"], cs.zoom)
    # Get player position on screen
    screen_position = coordsToPixels(game.posX - game.cameraX, game.posY - game.cameraY)
    # change screen position to center of screen
    screen_position = (screen_position[0] + (cs.resolution_width/2), screen_position[1] + (cs.resolution_height/2))
    # blit player to screen
    window.blit(scaled_player, (screen_position))
```

If you're concerned about memory, you can limit your caching with the [`lru_cache` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Answer (score 2):

> Is HW really natively supported, and if so, how does one go about working with it?

Yes, you can use hardware acceleration by using Textures instead of Surfaces. Pygame supports it by now, but note that [pygame's support is still marked as experimental](https://pyga.me/docs/ref/sdl2_video.html).

To learn how it works, maybe read a SDL2 tutorial like [this](https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/07_texture_loading_and_rendering/index.php).

Here's a simpe example I hacked together. You'll get the idea.

```
import pygame, io, base64
from pygame._sdl2 import Renderer, Texture, Window
from time import perf_counter as get_ticks

# It's a cat!
IMG = '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'

def main():
    pygame.init()

    # We need a Window object and a Renderer
    window = Window("SDL2", size=(640, 480))
    renderer = Renderer(window)

    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 32)

    fps = 0
    fps_timestamp = get_ticks()
    fps_t = Texture.from_surface(renderer, font.render('XXX', True, 'white'))
    
    # Just a pygame Surface...
    tmp_image = pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(IMG)))

    # ...converted into a Texure
    tex = Texture.from_surface(renderer, tmp_image)
    
    # Just some variables to let the image move around
    scale = 1
    scale_d = 0.0005
    rotation = 0
    
    # target = True allows us to render all stuff into this Texture before rendering it to the window
    buffer = Texture(renderer, (640, 480), target=True)
    
    # keep track of the zoom level
    zoom = 1
    
    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT or e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: 
                return
            if e.type == pygame.MOUSEWHEEL:
                if e.y > 0:
                    zoom += 0.1
                else:
                    zoom -= 0.1
        
        # Count the FPS             
        fps += 1
        if get_ticks() - fps_timestamp > 1:
            fps_timestamp = get_ticks()
            fps_t = Texture.from_surface(renderer, font.render(str(fps) + ' FPS', True, 'white'))
            fps = 0

        # start rendering onto the buffer texture
        # everything we do now with the renderer happens on that texture
        renderer.target = buffer

        # clear the buffer Texture
        renderer.draw_color = (10, 70, 90, 255)
        renderer.fill_rect(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 640, 480))
        
        scale += scale_d
        if scale >= 2 or scale <= 0.5: scale_d *= -1
        rotation += 0.02
        
        # note how we can set the size and angle of the Texture
        tex.draw(dstrect=(50, 50, 247*scale, 247*scale), angle=rotation)
        
        # start rendering on the screen
        # by setting target to None, everything happens now on the screen
        renderer.target = None

        # clear the screen
        renderer.draw_color = (0, 0, 90, 255)
        renderer.fill_rect(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 640, 480))

        # draw the buffer Texure on the screen
        buffer.draw(dstrect=((640-640*zoom)/2, (480-480*zoom)/2, 640*zoom, 480*zoom))

        # print some stuff
        zoom_t = Texture.from_surface(renderer, font.render(f'Zoom: {zoom:10.2f}', True, 'white'))
        zoom_t.draw(dstrect=(520, 450, 100, 30))
        fps_t.draw(dstrect=(10, 10, 75, 25))
        
        # update the window, like pygame.display.flip() does
        renderer.present()

main()
```

[Video](https://imgur.com/a/Xj2poKP)

Use the mouse wheel to zoom in/out.